# How to read a Multipartfile and return a Workbook?

Tags: java, multipartfile

I have a `Multipartfile` and I want to get the `Workbook` of it.
I use the following code for the same purpose but with the `File` instead of `Multipartfile`.

```
Workbook wb =  StreamingReader.builder().rowCachesize(200).bufferSize(4096).open(file); // file is of type File here
```

How, do I do the same but with Multipartfile?
Thanks for all the answers and comments in advance.

Comment: Are you using [POI](https://poi.apache.org/) ?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, no

Comment: What is class `Workbook`? What is class `StreamingReader`? Are they classes that you wrote? Pardon my ignorance, but what, exactly, is a _multipartfile_ ?